# What is the length of my array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello everyone I'm having trouble with strlen and arrays, it keeps saying my string length is only one? If anyone could help it would be great here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char word1[20];
    int len = strlen(word1);
    cout << "enter a word!\n";
    cin.get(word1, 20, '\n'); cin.ignore(50,'\n');
    cout << len;
}
```

Comment: You’re taking the length of `word1` before you put anything in it. `len` could be anything.

Comment: thank you so much! i didnt think that would matter because generally i define variables at the beginning anyways? but thank you again :)

Comment: @Code971 When the computer runs the line `int len = strlen(word1);`, what do you think `word1` contains?

Comment: anything? lol but shouldnt it be overwritten when characters are entered into the array? sorry im kinda new at this

Comment: If you run `len = strlen(word1)`, `len` stores whatever the length was at that time. Variables don’t update automatically. So if the string changes and you want the new length, then you have to run `len = strlen(word1)` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the back and forth in the comments, updating my answer to try and give some more intuition behind what's going on.

`char word1[20];` Sets a place in your computer's memory that can eventually be filled by data up to 20 characters. Note that this statement alone does not "clear" the memory of whatever is currently there. As sfjac has pointed out, this means that literally anything could be in that space. It's highly unlikely that whatever is in this space is a character or anything your code could readily understand.

`int len = strlen(word1);` Creates an integer and sets it equal to the value of the number of characters currently in `word1`. Note that, because we have not specified any content for `word1`, you're taking the length of whatever happened to be in that memory space already. You've limited the maximum to 20, but in this case, whatever data junk is in there is giving you a length of 1.

`cout << "enter a word!\n";` Prompt the user for a word

`cin.get(word1, 20, '\n'); cin.ignore(50,'\n');` Get the word, store it in `word1`. At this point, `word1` is now defined with actual content. However - you've already defined the variable `len`. The computer does not know to automatically redefine this for you. It follows the steps you provide, in order.

`cout << len;` Print the value stored in `len`. Because `len` was created prior to the user entering their data, `len` has absolutely nothing to do with what the user entered.

Hope this helps give you some intuition that will help beyond this one question!

Answer (score 1):

@Chris is correct but perhaps a small explanation. When you declare a character array like `char word1[20]` on the stack, the array will not be initialized. The `strlen` function computes the length of the array by counting the number of characters from the address of `word1` to the first null byte in memory, which could be pretty much anything.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using `std::string` for text.

If you must use character arrays:

- Define a named identifier for the capacity.
- Define the array using the named identifier.
- The capacity should account for a terminating nul, '\0', character to
  mark the end of the maximum text length.

Using the above guidelines you have the simple program:

```
int main(void)
{
  std::string a_word_string;
  std::string line_of_text_string;
  const unsigned int c_string_capacity = 32U;
  char c_string[c_string_capacity];

  // The std::string functions
  cout << "Enter some text: ";
  getline(cin, line_of_text_string); // read a line of text
  cout << "\nEnter a sentence: ";
  cin >> a_word_string;
  cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); // Ignore remaining text in the buffer.

  // The C-style string functions
  cout << "Enter more text: ";
  cin.read(c_string, c_string_capacity);
  c_string[c_string_capacity - 1] = '\0'; // Insurance, force end of string character
  cout << "You entered " << (strlen(c_string)) << " characters.\n";
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `std::string` class is more efficient and can handle dynamically size changes.

The length of the array is the value of `c_string_capacity` which was used when defining the array.

The length of the text in the array is defined as `strlen(c_string)`, which is the number of characters before the terminating nul is found.

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate `len` after reading in `word1`, otherwise you are left with undefined behaviour.

```
char word1[20];
cout << "enter a word!\n";
cin.get(word1, 20, '\n'); cin.ignore(50,'\n');
int len = strlen(word1);
cout << len;
```

It's a good idea to always initialize objects when you declare them. Since objects inside of a scope **are not guaranteed** to be initialized.
In C++11 for example,  you can do this:

```
char arr[10]{};  // this will initialize the objects in the array to default.
char arr[10]{0}; // the same.
```